# Compile error , Expected: end of statement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, filterxml

Following is the vba code, (just inserted formula in vba)

```
Sub xyz()
Range("H2").Formula = "=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","</s><s>"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(., '.'))]"))"
Range("H2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End Sub
```

But i get this error: highlighting ";" next to textjoin.

[image]

Please help to correct this code.

Comment: May i know which comma you are talking about?

Comment: Get it all working on one line first - it's much easier.

Comment: I have made it in one line, but still it gives the same error

Comment: You need to escape your double quotes inside your formula

Comment: You can't embed double quotes inside double quotes. Doing so means that your code is seen as `"=TEXTJOIN(";`, which is clearly incomplete and leaves a hanging semicolon. You need to escape the embedded double quotes.

Comment: does that mean I can use single quote instead of double quotes?

Comment: Double quotes in strings should be doubled up `a=“I said “”Hello”” to my friend”`

Comment: `Range("H2").Formula = "=TEXTJOIN("";"",TRUE, FILTERXML(""<t><s>""&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,""/"",""</s><s>""),"";"",""</s><s>"")&""</s></t>"",""//s[not(contains(., '.'))]""))"` I have corrected this, it has no errors ,but does not provide the expected output

Comment: @Lote_marsk_chozey re _but does not provide the expected output_.  That would be a new question.   This one has been answered (escape your quotes)

Comment: Problem could be due to your explicit referencing finding the last used row. Who knows. I agree; question is answered. Open a new question with more detailed information if you wondering about the unexpected output.